# Python/OpenCV camera capture resulting in blank/black images

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I have a webcam and I have installed the camera drivers and it is using the vendor's drivers (not UVC). I am trying to capture an image and it is resulting in an array of zeros (frame).  I have used another software on windows and it is able to get the video without issues. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
f1 = cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,  1920)
f2 = cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)
f2 = cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 1)
print(cam.get(3),cam.get(4))

if cam.isOpened():
    _,frame = cam.read()
cv2.imshow('',frame)
```

Edit: Please check the comments. I tried a few suggestions and they didn't work. I changed the camera, but with the new camera, I get noise.

Comment: Does cv2.VideoCapture(0) have the same result? How do you know that "1" is the correct ID?

Comment: camera built-in in notebook usually have ID 0. And sometimes camera need time to warm up so it may return zeros at start. Better check few frames later.

Comment: @fendall "1" is correct. I have another camera on "0" that works OK. The camera at "1"  works ok when I use a 3rd party web cam viewing software.

Comment: @furas I tried just that and the behavior didn't change. If I don't set the frame height and width, I get a noisy frame (not all zeros). I cannot assume that the webcam is bad as the webcam viewer software (.exe) works OK. No issues with that.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but I had similar issue with my camera, when I did not set a codec for it. I did it in C++. In Python it should be something like (maybe not exactly):

`cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(c1, c2, c3, c4))`  

where c1-c4 indicate the codec. First, try `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')`. Note, that this should probably be called **after setting camera resolution**!

Comment: @Dmsc: Thanks, but this resulted in an approximately 400x200 image (this is encouraging), but the rest of the 1920x1080 is still black.

Comment: @SEU That is quite strange. Is this image scaled to 400x200 or is this a subregion of the full image? At first, I would check now: 1) if I call setting codec after fps paramater (not only after setting width and height); 2) if I have proper codec installed; 3) if I can set any other codec than MJPEG; 4) if It still works bad on lower resolution.

Comment: I didn't find a solution to this problem completely, but it seems to be a hardware issue. When I changed the USB port on my PC to the one that's less used (behind), it worked OK.